# MYSQL subset operation

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to achieve something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_values
WHERE (value1, value2, value3) SUBSET_OF
    ( SELECT value
      FROM tb_value
      WHERE isgoodvalue = true
    )
```

**More information:**
I have a table called projects. Each project has tags. A tag can be shared by multiple projects. There is a mapping table called projectTagMap.  Now users use tags to filter the projects. Tags are selected using checkboxes on the UI. So a user selects several tags to filter the projects. Am supposed to select the projects from projects table that contains all the tags selected by the user.

Comment: You have described your question in terms of code. However, the purpose of the question is to obtain the correct code. The code you have given is, of course, not the correct code, so how are we supposed to figure out what you really want from it?! Use _words_ (and diagrams).

Comment: Which values are dynamic? The `value1, value2, value3` ones? And they can be 3 or possibly more or fewer?

Comment: the value1, value2 etc are provided by the user, say in stackoverflow, you want to select a question that has all the given set of tags. (my scenario is more complicated)

Comment: It would be better to show us your actual table with the actual field names. `value` and `tb_values` are not useful in providing semantic information.

Comment: @Tomalak initially i just wanted to know if there is a function or a trick that am missing in mysql. But now i have described the scenario and am more open to diverse suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your pseudo code I guess that you want to check if a (dynamic) list of values is a subset of another list provided by a `SELECT`. If yes, then a whole table will be shown. If not, no rows will be shown.

Here's how to achieve that:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_values
WHERE 
    ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value)
      FROM tb_value
      WHERE isgoodvalue = true
        AND value IN (value1, value2, value3)
    ) = 3
```

---

**UPDATED** after OP's explanation:

```
SELECT *
FROM project
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT projectid
      FROM projectTagMap
      WHERE isgoodvalue = true
        AND tag IN (tag1, tag2, tag3)
      GROUP BY projectid
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
    ) AS ok
    ON ok.projectid = project.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a primitive method but i suppose you could do:

```
WHERE value1 IN (SELECT value FROM tb_value WHERE isgoodvalue = true) OR value2 IN (...) ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, but my list of values is dynamic. The are provided by the user

Comment: Yeah i had a feeling it might be dynamic, don't know a way to do that without dynamically building the query in your scripting language