# Check if a set of integers is a subset of another set of integers

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using MariaDB 5.5, which at least covers all features available in MySQL 5.5, how can I find out if a set of integers is a subset of another subset of integers?

In other programming (non-database) languages, one does (for example Java)

```java
Set<Integer> innerSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1001, 1003));
Set<Integer> outerSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1001, 1003, 1005));
return outerSet.containsAll(innerSet);
```

In more informal notation:

```
innerSet = {1001, 1003}
outerSet = {1001, 1003, 1005}
return (innerSet is-subset-of outerSet)
```

Please note the values of the inner set and outer set concepts are not to be hard coded.

How can I achieve the same using MariaDB 5.5?

An example in pseudo-SQL, noting that `(..., ...)` is also reserved to denote columns, either:

```
SELECT {1001, 1003} SUBSET-OF {1001, 1003, 1005};
```

or

```
SELECT IS_SUBSET_OF({1001, 1003}, {1001, 1003, 1005});
```

Comment: Why using MariaDB (or MySQL, or indeed any other RDBMS)?

Comment: If speaking about DB, first you need to add into your question - how are you storing those "integer sets"? (as follows from your sample, those sets are just collections of numbers)

Comment: @Strawberry I currently have no other choice, unless there are very good arguments.

Comment: @AlmaDo Currently not storing them, that is a follow-up problem I am trying to solve, but I first absolutely need to get *is-subset-of* working.

Comment: If you're not storing them, then how DB is related to your issue after all?

Comment: Had a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121779/mysql-subset-operation ?

Comment: Databases are for the storage and retrieval of data. Relational databases are good at comparing rows of data with other rows of data.

Comment: @AlmaDo Because I will need to use this operation (*is-subset-of*) in a larger context, which is a stored procedure that gets executed on the database, with on one hand a set of input as parameter, and on the other hand sets of data (stored in normalized form) in the database.

Comment: Ok, then at least try to explain (in pseudo-SQL, may be) how it should look like. You already know that there's no "subset-of" operator for MySQL, but at least you can provide sample of what is input data and how that "operator implementation" should work

Comment: @AlmaDo I do not know if there is no "subset-of" operator in MySQL, I only know that it is not a function provided by default, I ask this question to figure out **if** there is a subset-of operator, then I can continue either by using it or by trying to work around it.

Comment: @skiwi start from the point: there are _no arrays_ in MySQL. You can emulate it with some temporary structure, but, again, it will be just mimic. Thus, I'm trying to get from you - what do you want from SQL, i.e. how "the syntax" should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason

`SELECT (COUNT(tableA.column) = COUNT(tableB.column)) FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.column = tableB.column`

Wouldn't work? You'd have to have both sets in a database column though.

Without a table, one nasty way I can think off would be to do this:

`SELECT (COUNT(tableA.a) = COUNT(tableB.b)) 
FROM (
  SELECT 10 as a 
  UNION 
  SELECT 20
) as tableA 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 10 as b 
  UNION 
  SELECT 20 
  UNION 
  SELECT 30
) as tableB ON tableA.a = tableB.b`

Comment: OP doesn't have any tables. And this has nothing to do with subset operation

Comment: @AlmaDo The data can be imported into a temp table.

Comment: Ah sorry, he was writing entire queries in chat and linked to this question, I had the idea he was using tables.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by first putting the data in temporary tables, and then executing a query on it, like this as example:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE inner_set;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE outer_set;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE inner_set
(value INT(11) NOT NULL, INDEX(value));
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE outer_set
(value INT(11) NOT NULL, INDEX(value));

INSERT INTO inner_set (value) VALUES (1001), (1003);
INSERT INTO outer_set (value) VALUES (1001), (1003), (1005);

SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS is_subset_of
FROM inner_set
LEFT JOIN outer_set ON inner_set.value = outer_set.value
WHERE outer_set.value  IS NULL
```

The trick here is that left joining the `inner_set` with the `outer_set` will produce `NULL` values for the `outer_set`, then you can count those and return a `0` or `1` depending on whether it is a subset.